# how to prevent token generation for decliened cards on stripe payment gateway?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am working with stripe payment gateway.

Flow -

1 . Generating token

2 . Creating payment

Generating Token - as per below code all is good and token it generating.

Now i would like to block or check the card is valid for payment while generating token.

For example - cvc is valid and generate token for that so it will get payment for sure.

```html
if ($this->request->is('post') && $this->request->getData('gtoken') == 'gtoken') {

                $planId = $this->request->getData('planid');
                $amount = $this->request->getData('finalamount');
                $cc = $this->request->getData('cc');
                $cardHolder = $this->request->getData('cardHolder');
                $expiryMonth = $this->request->getData('expiryMonth');
                $expiryYear = $this->request->getData('expiryYear');
                $cvc = $this->request->getData('cvc');

                // validate data and generate token
                if($cc) {
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "card[number]=".$cc."&card[exp_month]=".$expiryMonth."&card[exp_year]=".$expiryYear."&card[cvc]=".$cvc);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, STRIPE_SECRET_KEY. ":" . "");

                    $headers = array();
                    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

                    $tokendata = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

                    if(@$tokendata["error"]) {
                        if(@$tokendata['error']['param'] =='invalid_number'){
                            $this->Flash->error("Please Enter a Valid Card Number.");
                        } elseif(@$tokendata['error']['param']=='exp_month'){
                            $this->Flash->error("Please Enter a Valid Month.");
                        }
                        else {
                            $this->Flash->error($tokendata['error']['message'] );
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $token = $tokendata['id'];
                        $this->request->session()->write('payment',$this->request->getData());
                        $this->request->session()->write('paymenttoken',$token);
                        // flush save coupon onsession
                        $this->request->session()->write('isapplycoupon', false);
                        $this->savePayment();
                        return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'venues', 'action'=>'add']);
                    }
                    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
                    }
                    curl_close ($ch);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes definitely you can validate CVC while creating a token by passing an amount of 0.1$ while creating a token.

This feature is not documented anywhere in stripe documentation

see these blog post and stripe mailing list for more details

[link 1](https://www.masteringmodernpayments.com/blog/how-to-check-cvc-and-address-with-stripe-js)

[link 2](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.stripe.com/forum/#!topic/api-discuss/LkoJgtOnbKo)

Your updated code should look like this and use Stripe.js to create token

```
Stripe.card.createToken({
  number: '4242424242424242',
  exp_month: '12',
  exp_year: '2022',
  cvc: '987'
}, 100, stripeResponseHandler);
```

Comment: This solution has been deprecated for well over 4 years now. You should not be relying on this feature and it will likely stop working in the near future once they entirely remove it

Comment: apart from this there is no other method to authorize card while creating token. By default stripe authorizes card only when we attempt to charge

Comment: Yes, which is expected behaviour by Stripe and how you should build your integration. This will go away so you should not rely on this or recommend this solution IMO.

Comment: yes. for the moment we can have this. non-documented solutions always have a risk of depreciation